# showmodalDialog issue in chrome new version

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, showmodaldialog

Google chrome in new version removed showmodalDialog .
and my code with this browser doesn't work how can i solve my problem?

```
function AddTime(OfferTime) {
    var x = new Array();
    var ClsPartColeg = document.getElementById("ClassParam").value;
    x[0] = SrcName(ClsPartColeg, 'PartCombo');
    if (OfferTime)
        x[1] = OfferTime;
    else
        x[1] = '$$0$' + SrcName(ClsPartColeg, 'College') + '$';
    var s = showModalDialog("../HtmlPage/ClsTime.htm", x, "status:0;help:0;dialogWidth:420px;dialogHeight:100px");
    if (s)
        Perform('NewTime;Item=' + s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- Use jQuery soft modal plugin that's use iframe to display your modal URL and add blocking layer to prevent users from interacting with the parent page

2- Open your modal with `window.open` and use `onblur` and `onload` to keep focus on the modal page till user close it

```
<body onblur="self.focus()" onload="self.focus()">
```

The second method is annoying for the use and I do not recommend it